# Что делать с HDD?

Tags: hdd

Что посоветуете делать с HDD? Раньше (+- полгода назад) техсостояние было желтым и ошибок чтения не было, только нестабильные сектора.

[image: CrystalDiskInfo]

**UPD:** нажал в программе пересканировать, и вот результат

[image: CrystalDiskInfo-after]

Comment: бэкапьтесь @ используйте для не очень важных данных, фильмы там храните, например (у меня так парочка переехала в стимбокс и скрашивают вечера)

Comment: SSD by OCZ что можете сказать?

Comment: Немедленно бэкапьтесь, потом выясняйте остальное. Пока вы выясните, какой винт лучший в мире, у вас не останется данных. Нестабильные сектора на HDD — это признак приближающейся внезапной смерти.

Comment: У вас там еще события переназначения, жаль на скрине не видно реально переназначенных сколько. а диск надо менять ...